# How to prevent parallel execution on query with no hint

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle11g, parallel-processing

I'm trying to improve performance to specific query in my DB.
One of the tables in the query, has parallel degree which is greater than 1 in dba_tables.

I founded that if I add a hint of

> NO_PARALLEL

my query back to run very fast.

The problem is that I don't want to touch and change the source of query.

So I found this article:

http://intermediatesql.com/oracle/how-to-add-a-hint-to-oracle-query-without-touching-its-text/

which explain how to use alias with block names to create a profile and actually execute the hint with no touching the query.

I used it before for use an index even the optimizer decide to execute FTS.

But in case of parallel - I just didn't understand how to do that.

I just want to add the action that will simulate the no_parallel hint on the whole query.

Additionally, I don't want to set the parallel parameter or alter the session.. just change for this query.

Someone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forcing a single query to use `/*+ NO_PARALLEL */` is easy because it's a statement-level hint.  There's no need to add query block names or figure out Oracle's internal names.

Add the NO_PARALLEL hint to the query:

```
begin
    dbms_sqltune.import_sql_profile(
        sql_text => 'select /*+ parallel */ * from dba_objects',
        profile => sqlprof_attr('no_parallel'),
        name => '0ftu9j02g81b0_noparallel'
    );
end;
/
```

Verify that the statement has a profile and does not run in parallel:

```
explain plan for select /*+ parallel */ * from dba_objects;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

Results:

```
...

Note
-----
   - Degree of Parallelism is 1 because of hint
   - SQL profile "0ftu9j02g81b0_noparallel" used for this statement
   - this is an adaptive plan
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot! although I didn't recieve that result note which tells there is no use of parallel... but it change the action and the explain plan!

Answer (score 0):

So you do not want to:

- change the query itself
- change the degree on the table
- change session level parameters

It looks like a competency problem that a technical one.

If your query has fixed knows sql_id you can still use [sqlpatch](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/using-sql-patch-to-add-hints-to-a-packaged-application) to force the hint during parsing. sqlplatch is not the same as profile, and maybe it more suits your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I know that there are a lot of restrictions... The sqlpatch you send is for 12c version...